# How to handle eslint-disable-next-line conflict with prettier?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

With our Vuejs component based code, the eslint and prettier has a clash between start and close tags as shown in the below image. How to ignore this permanently? What's the best rule to handle this? Do we need to configure in eslint/prettier/both?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I run into this kind of thing a lot, and I've always solved it by wrapping the text content in a `<span>`. I know that isn't a very satisfying answer. Perhaps someone else will have a better suggestion.

Comment: @DavidWeldon - Thank you but expecting solution :)